# event.bytesLoaded - Access of undefined property event

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
1120: Access of undeined property event.
```

...is thrown for both event.bytesLoaded and event.bytesTotal

```
public class Main extends MovieClip {
    public function Main() {
        system_load.bar.scaleX = 0;
        this.stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this._loadUpdate);
    }

    private function _loadUpdate( e:Event ):void {
        var bl:int = event.bytesLoaded;
        var bt:int = event.bytesTotal;
        system_load.bar.scaleX = (bl/bt);
    }
}
```

I'm unsure of what to import to make this work. Currently has the following imported:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
```

Just ask and I'll provide with more details.

Comment: Where's your code that errors out?

Comment: I've now added the code. I don't normally ask questions online, so I don't know what's needed.

Comment: you give your event a name of 'e' but want to use it by 'event', come on that question shouldn't even be here.

Answer (score 0):

your event variable is called e and not event. Try:

```
private function _loadUpdate( event:ProgressEvent ):void {
        var bl:Number = event.bytesLoaded;
        var bt:Number = event.bytesTotal;
        system_load.bar.scaleX = (bl/bt);
    }
```

Edit: i suggest you to use ProgressEvent if you want to access to bytesLoaded and bytesTotal

Comment: This solution gets rid of those error messages; however, the result of (bl/bt) results in nothing (and I know that applying any number from 0 to 1 works, as when I manually input those values, I see the progressbar be constant filled to that point).

Comment: Your have to change type to Number for bl and bt
( see http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/ProgressEvent.html )

Comment: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.events::Event@7ff5fdaa4941 to flash.events.ProgressEvent.

Comment: I'm okay with that, you have to change the event dispatched and the event type of your: this.stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, this._loadUpdate);

Comment: Change it to what? That's what I'm trying to learn here. If I have it at `Event.ENTER_FRAME` - it triggers every frame, and if I change it to `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` (suggested below) it doesn't trigger at all.

_Also, is there a way to do Simulated Download in Flash CC? I can't seem to find it_

Comment: okay, so you want to catch this event particularly. I suggest you to clarify what you want. I don't understand why you need a progressEvent when you enter into a frame.

Comment: @Liggliluff : Each event dispatched has a type ( Event.ENTER_FRAME is in fact a string describing the event type. ) if you try to catch the ProgressEvent.Progress, you will catch all the event with this string id. And as you can see, Event.ENTER_FRAME is an other kind of event than ProgressEvent.Progress . That's what you have to clarify, try to understand which event is dispatched. The progressEvent is not dispatched by your component.

Comment: What I'm looking for is getting the value from `event.bytesLoaded` and update it every frame or so... or least once.

Comment: @Liggliluff I understood but the bytesLoaded property is thrown by an event named ProgressEvent. This event has to be dispatched. Usually, it's dispatched when you download or upload something from the internet ( through a socket for example ). What i have to understand to answer you is : which component is dispatching the event and what is the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this error is because the listener you added is using an `Event` type and not a `ProgressEvent`. The `ProgressEvent` class has the properties `bytesLoaded` and `bytesTotal`, whereas the `Event` class does not. What you are looking for is usage of the `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS`. An example would be:

```
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadUpdate );
```

Although your current implementation is not actually loading anything because you added the listener to the stage and not a loader, so the progress would not be displayed. For relevant examples check out the `ProgressEvent` class here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/ProgressEvent.html#includeExamplesSummary

Here's a quick and dirty example I put together loading an image:

```
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadUpdate );
myLoader.load( new URLRequest("path/to/image.png") );
```

Then you could just use your `loadUpdate()` as is.

Comment: Applying this solution will throw the error "Access of possibly undefined property contentLoaderInfo through a reference with static type flash.display:LoaderInfo", in addition to the previous errors.

Comment: Make sure you are typing this correctly and your loader is of type `Loader` .... `contentLoaderInfo` is definitely a property of `Loader`. Pleases refer to the link provided in the answer. More info on Loader here [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html)

Comment: Going through this more in detail, this looks more like loading extra data. I was looking for loading the actual SWF-file itself.